# Calling a method in other methods class, multiple times

Tags: class, oop

How to optimize calling a method within other method's class?
I have a method in a class called e.g. `print`. and I want it to call it in most other's method in the class.

something is fishy about calling a method again and again.
How to avoid forgetting calling that method?

I am totally sure I learned a solution for that before. but I don't remember it right now. Most questions and pages that I found were irrelevant.
hope the way I titled this question, help others!

```
class Printer() {

    public void print() {
    // print somthing...
    }

    public void func1() {
    // do some stuff...
    // ..
    print()
    }

    public void func2() {
    // ...
    // do some stuff...
    // ..
    print()
    }

    public void func3() {
    // ...
    }

    public void func2() {
    // ...
    print()
    // ...
    }
}
```

I'm not sure about inheritance and overriding method here...

Comment: There’s something fishy with your model if you have to run a method across other methods all the time.

Answer (score 0):

you can re-use using Static methods in a class

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static void Print()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

or you can use Extensions in like for example for a string

```
    public static void PrintString(this string str)
    {
        // your code ... return new string
    }
```

and use it like this

```
   "my text".PrintString()
```